# Lightbox loading, but image isn't

Tags: jquery

The light box pops up, but doesn't load the image. I have hacked this entire gallery together,  from Gallerific plugin and jQuery lightbox.

I have tried adding this to Gallerific plugin with little success:

```
            onTransitionIn: function() {
    $('#slideshow').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#slideshow span.image-wrapper').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#slideshow').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#slideshow span.image-caption').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#slideshow').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('a.lightbox').lightBox();
    });
},
```

http://lytesting.com/mdh/templates/mdh/gallery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are pointing to a `#hash_fragment` in your links. If you point them to the actual image source it will load into the lightbox.

Lightbox is trying to be unobtrusive and use graceful degradation, so linking to the image directly is also a good idea - so your page still works without javascript.

There may be ways to configure it with the #hash links, but by testing the above solution with Firebug, it worked for me in FF4.

```
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
    <span class="image-wrapper current">
        <a href="{YOUR_IMAGE_URL}" class="lightbox"> <!-- Instead of #2, etc. -->
            &nbsp;<img alt="Title #0" src="images2/art.jpg">
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. I see the image. The animation is a bit choppy, and the caption is duplicated, but the image appears.

Comment: This is what I thought at first, but click on the image after it loads within the page the to open the "lightbox", nothing loads.